# Postgres gist exclude time range except if the id is a specific value

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to come up with a table structure to disallow creating 2 events at the same time for a given community, except for if the community is "admin" with and id of 1. Our business logic is that "each community can only have 1 event at a time, but admins can create as many overlapping events as they like"

So far I have this, which is pretty straightforward, however I was not able to find a constraint to add "all except this" to this table

```
CREATE TABLE community_event (
    community_id integer,
    event_start timestamptz,
    event_end timestamptz,
    canceled boolean DEFAULT false,
    EXCLUDE USING gist (
        community_id WITH =, tstzrange(event_start, event_end) WITH &&
    ) WHERE (not canceled)
);
```

how can I add this requirement to it?

Comment: 'admin' is the name of a community?

Comment: yeah, "admin" or some other value that I want to give more power to

Comment: Please make the description match the table definition. `community_id` is type  integer and can't take a string like 'admin'.

Answer (score 3):

ok, I was actually close. just needed to add the condition in the WHERE clause.

```
CREATE TABLE community_event (
    community_id integer,
    event_start timestamptz,
    event_end timestamptz,
    canceled boolean DEFAULT false,
    EXCLUDE USING gist (
        community_id WITH =, tstzrange(event_start, event_end) WITH &&
    ) WHERE (not canceled AND community_id != 1)
);
```

Comment: Was about to post the same.